# Symfony : route containing '/'

Tags: php, symfony

I've got a problem.

This is my route currently :

```
edit_declaration:
    pattern:    /X/Y/{idDeclaration}/{token}/{modification}
    defaults:   { _controller: SgaDemandeBundle:Demande:editDone}
    requirements:
        token:  .+
```

Then :

```
http://website/X/Y/myIdDeclaration/A4Z5TvCgPoBW+iP6BO0NsVW2ya0J9ME/gIeiJ+q0lGw=/OK
```

My token can have `'/'`.

Here my token is : `A4Z5TvCgPoBW+iP6BO0NsVW2ya0J9ME/gIeiJ+q0lGw=`

But my token is cut after `'/'` like that :

```
A4Z5TvCgPoBW+iP6BO0NsVW2ya0J9ME/
```

instead of

```
A4Z5TvCgPoBW+iP6BO0NsVW2ya0J9ME/gIeiJ+q0lGw=
```

I followed this example : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Seemingly this is working without using another behind.

Help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood the exemple in the doc. The exemple allow you to pass 2 different parameters separate by a slash.

You have to use [urlencode](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode slash and other characters to safe interpretation.

By default parameters are url encoded in Symfony2, how do you generate the route?

**EDIT :**
in the comment, you say you are using `<a href='{{path}}/{{declaration.idDeclaration}}/{{ token|url_encode() }}'>`
please, use the routing generation system of symfony:

```
<a href='{{ path('nameOfThePath', {'id': declaration.idDeclaration, 'token': token }}'>
```

This way, if one day you want to change your route you will not have to pass on all your pages...

Comment: In fact, I pass a link through email twig template like that :

<a href='{{path}}/{{declaration.idDeclaration}}/{{ token }}'>{{ declaration.idDeclaration }}</a>.

Then when the user clicks my url is not encoded seemingly

Comment: I 've just added <a href='{{path}}/{{declaration.idDeclaration}}/{{ token|url_encode() }}'> then its working fine for the time being. thanks bud

Comment: Why not use the twig function `path('edit_declaration', {'idDeclaration': declaration.idDeclaration, 'token': token })` to generate your url? Although this will error out as you would be missing the modification parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When generating token use [urlencode](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.urlencode.php). So `/` becomes `%2F`